# Regex C# to allow colons and parenthesis in addition to numbers and letters

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex currently that allows letters, numbers, underscore and hyphen. Also allows string to be only between 1 and 255 characters long. I need to add to this regex to allow colon and parenthesis. Please assist. I tried a lot of variations and am at the loss.Just adding : and () to the list is not doing the trick.
So if someone checks against this regex, it should allow string like ABCabc123():_-

```
 @"^[a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,255}$"
```

Comment: Should it allow strings like ABCabc)( with parenthesis unmatched?

Comment: yes. in any order...doesn't even have to be together.. can be ABCac12):_(

Comment: `^[:\(\)a-zA-Z0-9_-]{1,255}$`

Comment: https://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html#special has more information about escaping characters that have special meanings in regular expressions.

Comment: Try this ^[a-zA-Z0-9_:()-]{1,255}$

Comment: Please show the regular expression that isn't working and the code you're using to test it that shows it not working.

Comment: wow.. interesting. John, your solution works (I think) still testing. I was trying to put colon and parenthesis after _- that didn't work but between seems to do the trick

Comment: `-` has a very specific meaning in a character class. If you're not careful with what goes before and after it, it will be interpreted differently... post your actual regex and actual errors.

Comment: I used John's Regex in comments. It is working like I need it. Thank you everyone. 
I don't know how I can mark his answer correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just escape parentheses like `\(` and `\)`, anything else should be fine:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9-_\(\):]{1,255}$
```

Comment: There is no need escaping `(` and `)` as they are not special inside character classes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew, Thanks a lot, actually i didn't know that as i had always escaped them ;)